# Initializing a large map in header cause g++ crashes

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, header-files

I am trying to make a simple tool that requires some lookup on a fixed key-value dataset, so I try to lazily throw all data to a hashmap in the header file:

```cpp
/** main.h */
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

const unordered_map<uint64_t, const char * const> test = {
    {0xDEADC0DE, "Some short text less than 50 characters"},
    // 46K rows of data
};
```

I haven't implemented anything yet, but just including this header file is enough to crash the compiler.

main.cpp

```
/** main.cpp */
#include <iostream>
#include "main.h"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

After maxing out a CPU core for 5 minutes, the g++ (cc1plus) eats up all 32GB of RAM and crashes. I know a large header could impact compiling performance but I did not expect it to exhaust resources and fail. How does it use up 32GB RAM when the size of the header file is only 1.9 MB? Could someone please help explain the problem in my case?

The version I am using is g++ (GCC) 13.2.1 20230801, with the command `/usr/bin/g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -o CMakeFiles/main.cpp.o -c /home/foo/main.cpp`

### Update

I also did some experiments with different sizes of map:

| Element Number | Build Time |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 00:00:01.043 |
| 100 | 00:00:01.187 |
| 1000 | 00:00:05.225 |
| 2000 | 00:00:10.200 |
| 5000 | 00:00:25.604 |
| 10000 | 00:00:52.208 |
| 20000 | 00:01:48.090 |

### Update

The problem is solved by disabling compiler optimization. I am using the VS Code CMake extension and the Release profile adds `-O3` to the g++ argument. Removing this allows the project (46K rows) to be compiled in 6 seconds. The compiler must be trying hard to cast some optimization magic that unfortunately goes wrong.

Comment: Does it *have* to be done at compile-time? Can't you store it in a simple text-file and load it at program startup?

Comment: Of course, that is one of the possible workarounds, though with some overhead on start-up. I just wonder if someone knows the details behind this resource consumption problem. It would be good if we could find a way to make this piece of code work.

Comment: I would hate to nitpick but this `std::unordered_map` should be declared in a source file such that it will have static storage duration and will be `extern`ed

Answer (score 4):

*The large header file is killing your performance. Don’t bully your compiler!*

Imagine `include`ing `<main.h>` —which as you say has over *forty-six thousand (46000 + 1) elements*— in every source file that needs it. That would mean you duplicate the large object `test` everywhere you include it and your compiler is forced to preprocess the header and compile it everywhere it is included. This is bad! really bad!!

Like I mentioned in my comment, this object `test` should be in a translation unit, should have static storage duration and should have external linkage. This is so that it will be compiled once, will live till program termination and can be made available in other translation units by using the `extern` keyword to refer to it.

`test.cpp`

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cstdint>

const std::unordered_map<uint64_t, const char* const> test {
    {0xDEADC0DE, "Some short text less than 50 characters"},
    /* 46K rows of data */
};
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cstdint>

extern const std::unordered_map<uint64_t, const char* const> test;

int main() {
    std::cout << test[0xDEADC0DE] << '\n';
    return 0;
};
```

Anywhere you want to use `test`, simply declare it `extern` and you will be referring to the same object in static storage. This way, you will avoid copying `test` and also save some compilation costs.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the issue in my case, as my problem seems to be caused by the compiler optimization option. However, thank you for the suggestion. It is helpful to align my code with best practices.

Comment: Well while you consider the suggestion, you will still compile the program for `Release` won’t you? Don’t write the large object in a header so that you don’t have to recompile that every time.